Duplicate entries created during bulk publish in Strapi v5
In Strapi v5, we've encountered an issue with the Draft & Publish feature where using the bulk publish action creates duplicate entries instead of updating the publishedAt state of existing drafts.
For example, when creating a draft entry (e.g., products) and publishing it via bulk action in the admin UI, a new entry is created while the original draft remains unchanged. This behavior causes database bloat and bypasses content-type lifecycle hooks, even when explicitly blocking creation during publish operations.
Publishing should update the publishedAt field of the existing entry rather than duplicating it. We’re using draftAndPublish: true in our content type settings.
Has anyone experienced this issue or found a solution?
